# ¿Cómo puedo crear un contador de tablas mediante js?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo mi HTML, y yo quiero crear dentro del div con la clase nums, un contador de unas tablas que se crean mediante una base en SQL, la tabla la tengo así:

```
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Tabla de Resultados de Football</h5>
        <p id="tables-count"></p>
        <hr>
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name Team 1</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php 
                    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_football)){  
                ?>
                <tr class="align-middle table-football">
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['date_soccer']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['team_soccer_1']; ?></td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Y justo abajo de esta tabla tengo este div con un id, y quiero mediante js crear un botón que separe las tablas mediante números (ósea 1 2 3 4 5 ...), y bueno, quiero que cada 5 tablas se cree un botón, a continuación es donde quiero que mediante js con algún algoritmo se cree los botones a medida que se crean las tablas, y a la vez pueda seleccionar un botón y que me muestre las tablas que estén en esa sección ósea (sección 1 2 ...), no se si me explico

```
<div class="table_nums">
    <div class="nums" id="nums-foot">
            
    </div>
</div>
```

estaba intentando algo en js pero no encuentro la manera de poder hacer lo que quiero lograr, simplemente que cada 5 tablas que se cree, se inserte en un div un botón con una clase un id y un valor de un numero (eso dependería de cuantas tablas hay, ya que quiero que cada 5 tablas se cree un botón, entonces si hay 15 tablas, van a crearse 3 botones 1, 2 y 3) y de esta manera esconder las tablas que se van creando con PHP con js, ya que si selecciono el botón  de sección 3 me muestre los últimos 5 creados nomas, y si selecciono el botón de sección 1 me muestre los primeros 5 creados.

No sirvo para explicarme, espero que me sepan entender, hace tiempo que estoy con lo mismo y no encuentro tutoriales ni ninguna pagina que explique bien como hacer :)

Answer (score 0):

No tengo claro si lo que quieres conseguir es poner un botón cada 5 `tablas` o cada 5 `filas` dentro de la misma `tabla`.

Porque si fuese el primer caso, en tu código, solamente se crea **una** `tabla` y el `while` está iterando `filas` de ésta.

Suponiendo que es así, que lo que quieres es pintar un botón cada 5 `filas` y que este botón sirva para ocultar todas las filas menos las que le corresponen por `id`, el enfoque que deberías tomar es la funcionalidad **Collapse** de [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/) ya que hace justo lo que necesitas.

También es posible que te pueda servir este código que he encontrado en red:
[Mostrar Div y Ocultar Otro[Bootstrap]](https://codepen.io/AngelKrak/pen/LpVrBr)

Y respecto a como mostrar el botón solamente cada 5 `filas`, eso se consigue con un contador y haciendo que se pinte el botón solamente cuando este contador es divisible por 5:

```
if($contador % 5 == 0)
  'pinto el botón
```

Espero que te pueda servir mi contribución.